# In Vue can I use html elements like <href> in data?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, jsx

I have a lot of data strings like this:

```
    data(){
      return(){
        {name:"ex",title:"exTitle",desc:"exDesc exDesc ....."},
        {name:"ex2",title:"ex2Title",desc:"exDesc2 exDesc2....."


      }

    }
```

I want make some part of the "desc" strings bold or link. I tried to do this

```
        {name:"ex",title:"exTitle",desc:"exDesc exDesc ....."},
        {name:"ex2",title:"ex2Title",desc:<p> <b>exDesc</b> exDesc..... </p>
```

It gives me an error that says I need to use jsx or typescript. But I couldn't find anything about this. Is this something I could do? Or are there different things that I can do?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use HTML but you need to put it between quotes like other strings :

```
{name:"ex",title:"exTitle",desc:"exDesc exDesc ....."},
{name:"ex2",title:"ex2Title",desc: "<p> <b>exDesc</b> exDesc..... </p>"}
```

To use a data with HTML in you're template you can put it in a v-html like this :

```
<span v-html="desc"></span>
```